# Prove SST=SSTr+SSE

Tags: anova, mathematical-statistics, sums-of-squares

How can I prove that SST=SSTr+SSE (anova) when

I have that

$SST =\sum_i \sum_j (x_{ij}-\bar x_{..} )^2$

$SSTr =\sum_i \sum_j (\bar x_{i.}-\bar x_{..} )^2 $

$ SSE= \sum_i \sum_j (x_{ij}-\bar x_{i.} )^2$

Comment: Check earlier posts, this is likely to have been answered before.

Comment: Try YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFdlFoHI_0I

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$SST =\sum_i \sum_j (x_{ij}-\bar x_{..} )^2 = \sum_i \sum_j (x_{ij}-\bar x_{..} + \bar x_{i.} - \bar x_{i.})^2$ and expand the summand.